# Create double const pointer from two variables

Tags: c, pointers

I have a function that takes a `const char**` as an parameter. The `const char**` holds a file list like `a.1`, `a.2`, `a.3`, `a.4`, `a.5` and so on.

How can I create such a double pointer? I have the name (like `a` above as `const char*`) and the file count (like `1`, `2`, `3`... as `unsigned int`) in two different variables.

I already tried to declare the `const char**` taking a `for` loop until `file_count max` is reached and use `sprintf` to concatenate in the loop, but it did not work.

```
int x;  
const char** files;

for ( x = 0; x < max_files; x++ ) {
    sprintf(files, name".%d", x)
}
```

Comment: Show your code, we show your error. It should work with a for loop and sprintf()

Comment: I added what I tried in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for `files` and then, for each element of it too using `malloc` before writing to it because `files` points to some random memory location(Because you did not initialize it). Use:

```
files = malloc( max_file * sizeof(*files)); //sizeof(*files)==sizeof(char*)

for(int i=0; i < max_file ; i++)
{
    files[i] = malloc( 20 );               // Allocating some reasonable size
    sprintf(files[i] , "%s,%d" , names,x); // Making the string
}

// After the use of `files[i]` and `files`, free the allocated memory:

for(int i=0; i <max_file ; i++)
    free(files[i]);
free(files);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a function that takes a `const char**` as an parameter.

This does not mean that you must pass it a `const char**`. Passing `char**` will work as well.

> I already tried to declare the `const char**` taking a for loop until `file_count` max is reached

Your loop prints into `files` without allocating memory for it. You need to `malloc` the `files` first, and then its individual items:

```
char** files = malloc(sizeof(char*) * max_files);
for (int x = 0; x < max_files; x++ ) {
    files[x] = malloc(12); // name+dot+digits+'\0'
    sprintf(files[x], "name.%d", x);
}
```

At this point you can pass `files` to a function taking `const char **`. Once the function returns, you need to free the allocated memory, like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < max_files; x++ ) {
    free(files[x]);
}
free(files);
```